# What type of input value uses sizeof function in C?

Tags: c, types, sizeof

I have question regarding `sizeof` function in C. I wanted to write some function to get bit size of a given type. I'm a newbie and have very little experience with C so i wondered if i want to have a following structure what should be my input type?

```
int bits(  /*what TYPE goes here?*/ input  ) {
    return (8*sizeof( input ));
}
```

As you can see my input passed straight down to sizeof, so which type should i pass to my function prototype to make it work correctly?

Comment: You mean you want to use it like `bits(int)` ? That cannot be done using a function. And `sizeof` returns type `size_t`.

Comment: @YuHao thanks, i know that it returns size_t but size_t is a long unsigned int for me (I don't know is it compiler or OS dependent) so i wrote `int` should it be the whole `long unsigned int` instead?

Comment: Yes, `size_t` is implementation-defined. You can use `size_t` directly, it's a type name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C is statically typed, so you cannot pass a type to a function. There is no way to do this with functions. But it works when you use a function-like macro:

```
 #define bits(type) (8*sizeof(type))

 printf ("The type 'int' is %zu bits wide\n", bits(int));
```

Terminology nit pick: `sizeof` is not a function; it is an *operator*. You can use it without the parentheses when the argument is an expression, as in

```
int i;
size_t j = sizeof i;
```

Note also that multiplying by 8 is an assumption that may be wrong. It's a safe bet for anything you can buy these days, but way back when memory was measured in kBytes (=1024 :-) there were some strange beasts where that was not true. And the C Standard also talks of *padding bits* which may complicate matters further, but I've never seen one in the wild.

Comment: +1 for reminding me, i have heard it already but totally forgot (i mean that sizeof is an operator). Why are you using `%zu` shouldn't be `%lu`?

Comment: I'm using `%zu` because that's the (C99) format for a `size_t`, the type that `sizeof` yields. Use `%lu` for `unsigned long`.

Comment: Given the likely size of any type, the precise use of `%zu` is probably less important than getting the number of bits in a `char` right for which `CHAR_BIT` should be used.  `sizeof(char)` is always 1, but `CHAR_BIT` is not always 8.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` is *not* a function, but an operator.  Moreover it is evaluated as a compile-time constant not a run-time variable.  It takes an operand that is either a type name or an expression, but in the latter case it is the size of the *type* of the result of the expression that is evaluated.

Note that while multiplying the size by eight will yield the bit size on most platforms, it is not true of all (TI TMS320C55x DSPs for example have a 16 bit char type).  A safer method is to use the CHAR_BIT macro defined in the standard limits.h header.

You can create a macro to evaluate bit-size:

```
#include <limits.h>
#define bit_sizeof(t) (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(t) )
```

This macro can, like sizeof, take either a type name or a variable argunent, which you cannot do with a function.

Comment: Minor nitpick: the operand of the sizeof operator is either a (parenthesised) typename, or an *expression*. No name is needed, the name decays into an expression. so `sizeof(1+1)` should also work (and probably yield `sizeof(int)` )

Comment: A good way to illustrate this is: `sizeof '@' == sizeof(int)` in C. (in C++, `sizeof 'A' == sizeof(char)` , IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is used to calculate the size of any datatype. You can pass either a primitive data type like an `int` or a `float` or user defined data type like a `struct`.

Comment: thanks, but what type should i specify for my input value, since it first passed to my bits function?

Comment: @orustammanapov since `C` does not provide function overloading, it is better to use a macro to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` operator can be used for any data types but cannot be used with function types, or bit-field lvalues.

You can have any type (primitive or user defined in your function)